# Transition not working when changing from display none to block

Tags: css, transition

I've noticed that `transition` is not working when the element is also changing from `display` `none` to `block`. Why is that? It works if I remove the `display` attribute.

CSS:

```
#box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: red;
    transform: scale(0);
    display: none;
    transition: transform .5s;
}
    #box.active {
        transform: scale(1);
        display: block;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/640kL55u/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it has `display: none` to begin with, the other styles are not being taken into the dom to be transitioned once `display: block` is added.

Instead, you can hide the div with height, so its still on the page but not showing. Then add the height on the `show` div.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/640kL55u/2/)

Answer (score 4):

Any change from or to `display: none` won't trigger transitions.

You can, however, change the `display` property and then add the class name at the end of the javascript stack. For instance:

```
function showElem(elem) {
  elem.style.display = "block";

  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.classList.add("active");
  }, 0);
}
```

And then pass element nodes to this function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't transition with `display: none;` properties...

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {

  $("#box").addClass("active");

});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform .5s;
}
#box.active {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: Im not transitioning the display property, only the transform.

Comment: It's because of the `display: none;` the other properties aren't being used.

Comment: Did you run my example?