# Why does animating opacity with the animation property work when the initial state is using `display: none`?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

## Using `animation`

The following animates the opacity of `.child` when it's initially set to `display: none;`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper .child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}

.wrapper:hover .child {
  display: block;
  animation: fadeOut 1s ease forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child">

  </div>
</div>
```

Attempting to use `transition` instead of `animation` does not work.

## Using `transition`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper .child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}

.wrapper:hover .child {
  display: block;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child">

  </div>
</div>
```

How does this work in the `animation` case and why does this not work in the `transition` case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481972/transition-not-working-when-changing-from-display-none-to-block

Comment: And more about animations from here: https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/keyframes/  _"The main difference is that while transitions trigger implicitly when property values change (for example, when a property value changes on hover), animations are explicitly executed when the animation properties are applied."_

Comment: @disinfor thank you, that is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding as an answer to aid in future visitors.

From this link: https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/keyframes/ here is the relevant portion:

*"The main difference is that while transitions trigger implicitly when property values change (for example, when a property value changes on hover), animations are explicitly executed when the animation properties are applied."*

This is an important distinction between `transition` and `animation`.

Here is a related answer about `display: none` and transitions after `display: block` has been set (as posted in the comments from user David): [Transition not working when changing from display none to block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481972/transition-not-working-when-changing-from-display-none-to-block)